# How to add different fallback intents for different intents

Tags: chatbot, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

How to add different fallback intents for different intents? So that user will see appropriate message instead of common fallback message.

Comment: Fallback Intents are triggered if a user's input is not matched by any of the regular intents or enabled built-in Small Talk. what exctly do you want
https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents#fallback_intents

Comment: Suppose there is wedding planner BOT and there are 2 intents. One is for handling catering related queries and one is for handling Costumes related queries. I want to give 2 different replies in both cases if BOT fallbacks to understand user queries

Answer (score 3):

If you are developing your own webhook to handle requests and response, it would be better to use Default Fallback intent for all the intents.
Add an output context to each of your individual intents and based on this context you can respond back from the webhook using the single Default Fallback Intent like

```
switch(inputContextToDefaultFallback){
  case "context1"...
  case "context2"...
}
```

But if all your intents are not using webhook, then you can add a fallback intent from the dialogflow by clicking Add follow-up intent --> then selecting fallback
like this [image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to add different Fallback intents for different contexts, you should just follow the steps provided in the documentation to [add a new Fallback intent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents#add_a_new_fallback_intent).

To do so, go to the three dots *more options* menu next to the *Create intent* button in the *Intents* tab in the Dialogflow UI, and then click on the *Create Fallback Intent* option. Once there, you  will be able to create a fallback intent, where you need to specify the **Input Context** (which should be the context under which you want this fallback intent to trigger), and **Responses**

Answer (score 0):

You can add different Fallback Intents to handle different user replies to what your Action has asked. Just like you can add different Intents to specifically handle based things you've asked or said.

The trick in both these cases is to set an Output Context along with with your reply, and then to require this as an Input Context for the regular Intents and Fallback Intents that you wish to be valid in this context.