# How do I create a general fallback intent for when user repeats question?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to make an intent for when the user repeats them self. (Chatbot)

Example:


User: "Can you help me?"

Bot: "Yes, of course I can"

User: "Can you help me?"

Bot: "I think you asked me that before"

I know it is possible to do with a follow-up intent, but how do I create a general fallback intent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add different fallback intents for different intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51317450/how-to-add-different-fallback-intents-for-different-intents)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It wasn't quite what I thought. I am looking for a way to make a global fallback if the user repeats themselves.

Comment: How would you catch the user repeats? It seems that you need to make a counter for each unrecognized intent to monitor the fallback event occurrence.